# .net core Serilog not working on Server, but works fine on local

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, serilog

We have written global logging functionality in one of our .Net Core 3.1 version solution and we are sending error details from .Net solution with version 4.7.2 with below lines of code..

```
string URL = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["netCoreSolutionURL"]) + "AppLogging/LogCSharpError"; 
using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
   MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   var response = client.PostAsync(URL, new 
   StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(appLog).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8,application/json")).Result; 
   //var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; 
}
```

Everything works fine on Local and error gets logged in the respective folder with error details. But the issue is on the Server where we hosted the both application, application is not logging any errors which are sent from the .Net solution, neither event viewer printing any error and we have given full access to the folder where application writing the logs. (Logging solution is logging the application start event longs which are triggered by the same solution)

Please let me know, whether I'm missing anything/server configuration or any security protocol details here while deploying on Server IIS 10.0?
(we are using Serilog to log errors/information)

Comment: I guess your application can't reach the netCoreSolutionURL from within your production network, but it is reachable from the outside when you run it locally. See these two posts here https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat

https://superuser.com/questions/1360221/how-to-access-my-public-ip-from-lan